# Sorting PySpark Dataframes on worker nodes in parallel

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a list of distributed spark dataframes at my master node, I want to sort each of them on separate worker node (my spark cluster conatins 4 nodes) and in parallel. Is it possible using map() or flatMap()? Or any thing else. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sortWithinPartitions` method which sorts the data in parallel for each partition. Every worker has its own partitioned data.

From my experience with a list of 1000000 random nos. `sortWithinPartitions` gives performance boost of 2x.

```
//Create a list with size 1000000 of random nos.
      spark.sparkContext.parallelize(for (i <- 1 to 1000000) yield  r.nextInt(1000000) )
        .toDF // Convert to dataframe with single column 'value'
        .sortWithinPartitions(col("value"))  // Sort the partition in parallel i.e. similair to sortin data on each worker
        .sort(col("value"))                  // Final sort on complete data set
        .map(r=>r.getInt(0)).collectAsList().toSeq // Collecting the result in list
```